# Why does https://domain-name.example work but www.domain-name.example throws 404 error

Tags: html, web, dns

Why does https://vivian-duong.gitlab.io work but www.vivian-duong.gitlab.io throw an error?

Answer (score 0):

Here the domain is gitlab.io. But vivian-duong.gitlab.io is the sub domain. The www prefix doesn't work before sub domain. You have to add a CNAME to vivian-duong.gitlab.io to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no web server configured to listen for requests for www.vivian-duong.gitlab.io.

It's the same as if you requested non-existant-name.vivian-duong.gitlab.io. As far as the web server is concerned, it's a request for something it doesn't have.

Someone needs to setup the web server to listen and respond to requests for www.vivian-duong.gitlab.io.

DNS is resolving to the correct IP address, however the web server isn't configured to respond to that host header.